# Disadvantages of Integrated Graphics Processor

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, nvidia-geforce, intel-graphics, integrated-graphics

I recently upgraded pretty much everything on two of my systems but my NVIDIA GeForce 210 1GB Graphic Cards.

One of my system has Intel Core i3 4130 which has Intel HD Graphics 4400 and the second one has Intel Core i5 4440 which has Intel HD Graphics 4600.

Since the GeForce 210 is a really old card, I am getting low FPS even on the lowest resolution and settings.

I should get a greater FPS if I use my integrated graphics because they are faster but I was wondering what would be the downsides of doing so apart from the decreased RAM available to system? Should I remain on GeForce 210? Also I was wondering if there is a way to combine the graphics processing power of both the GPUs and output it through the NVIDIA card?

---

Update: I cleaned and reapplied fresh thermal paste today and now the CPU isn't overheating. Idle temperature is now around 46 C. Using the integrated Intel HD Graphics 4400, I'm getting around 24 FPS on 1366 x 768 in Most Wanted 2012 (and 12 FPS on 1080p) but the maximum temperature the CPU package reached was 73 C. :)

Thanks @Hennes and everyone else.

Comment: Even the Intel HD 4400 is substantially more powerful than the GeForce 210. See, for example, http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/compare.php?cmp%5B%5D=1169&cmp%5B%5D=2643&cmp%5B%5D=2451

Comment: Heh, I just linked that site in my anser (before reading this comment). A useful site indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The downsides would be:

- The lack of dedicated RAM on the graphics card,
- and you would have more active silicon on your CPU+GPU die, meaning the CPU might get hotter.

The upsides are bigger though:

- The card is older, the on die GPU's are more modern. They use a lot less power, which means less heat, less cooling and a lower electricity bill.
- You gain a free expansion slot on your motherboard
- The on die GPU is a lot faster. Benchmarks never tell the full story, but the on-die Intel GPU is roughtly 2-3x as fast according to [this site](http://videocardbenchmark.net/gpu_list.php)

> Is there a way to combine the graphics processing power of both the GPUs

Theoretically: Yes. In practice: nope.

In order to use both CPU's you would need to present the OS a virtual graphics card which known how to use both real chips. There have been some attempts to do that, but usually it is not worth it.

> Should I remain on GeForce 210?

I would dump the old card unless you want to use it for PhysX.
Note that even used as PhysX card it may be old enough to actually yield **slower** results than not using it at all.

---

Update after lots of comments:

An idle temparature of

An idle temperature around 50°C with 40°C Ambient is not awful. 
That is a delta of +10°C.

It is not great either. I have checked my own Skylake CPU's and idle temps for both of them are +6°C. One with the Intel stock cooler, the other with cheap aftermarket cooling since it did not ship with a cooler.

+10°C is still 50% worse than +6°C though.  I asked people who live in hot parts of the world and they are stay well below your idle delta.  It probably means that something is suboptimal with your cooling. Either the thermal paste has dried out, is not applied correctly, the cooler is mounted wrong, or the inside of you case does not probaly a proper airflow.

When you try to run games you start using the CPU more intensely and you got more heat from the build-in GPU. THat should have means that the chip got hotter. Fan might spin faster. However given the capabilities of you modern chip vs the old card I expect that you would get 2x to 3x better performace with the on-die GPU.

... Except that it got very hot. Hot enough to throttle itself, lowing game performance significantly.  Combined with the already high differnce in idle temps I would:

1. Check the case openings (including dust filters. Those being clogged might explain things).
2. Check if you have multiple fans. IN case that yu do, which fan pushes air, which one pulls? How does the air flow through the case?
3. Check and remount the heatsink with fresh thermal paste.

If all goes well cooling should be significantly improved. At idle the point might be moot, but when gaming the CPU should stay cool and performance should be significantly better with the on-die GPU.

Comment: I'd honestly toss out the Phys-X option because with integrated graphics and a 210 you aren't going to be playing games that would utilize the feature above _maybe_ 720p, and certainly not with comparable video settings enabled. Especially not at the detriment of the benefits gained by removing the card entirely (power/noise/space savings)

Comment: I agree that I would toss it. But am am not familiar enough with PhysX to know the cut-off point for a usable card.

Comment: In my experience, PhysX can provide a marginal bump in framerate for certain games which utilize it (remarkably few, but some good titles). The OPs computer is perfect for games that aren't rendering in 3D, but will be severely hamstrung as soon as it loads anything made by a major developer in the last 5 years.

Comment: Would there be any impact on performance of the CPU?

Comment: If you max out the on-die GPU then the chip will be warmer and there will be less headroom for exeeding it is normal thermal budget. (read: it might not turbo as long as as without using the graphics). I suspect that the differene will only show up in benchmarks and that you will not notice it.

Comment: I removed the GeForce 210 and switched to Intel HD Graphics 4400 on i3 4130. Now I'm getting around 26 FPS in Most Wanted 2012 at 720p. But I noticed that while playing, my CPU temperature touches 100 C. I should probably put my 210 back, right?

Comment: It will  depend per game, per driver version and per system. (Cooling is different for each system, your dedicated graphics card could be a boost or it could dump needless heat in a case hampering CPU cooling). This means there is no guaranteed answer to this. Based on common assumption my answer would be 'no, the on-GPU should be able to do better', but also '100C? WTF? Modern CPU's do not commonly reach that temperature anymore. How hot is it when the system is idle?

Comment: Idle temperature is around 50 C (with the integrated graphics enabled). I should also add that the average high temperature for a day here is around 40 C in the summers.

Comment: Ah, good point to mention the ambient temperatures. I am currenly shivering in a much colder climate. Yes, that would offset temperatures 80C (as in ambier 20+60) is high over here, but not worrying. Neither is 100C (40+the same60) unless it reach t_junction and the CPU is thotling.

Still, temperature on my latest CPU's have a much lower deltra at idle. My i7-920 idles at ambient+12C, and the pentium G4400 and i5-6600K even dropped below that delta.  So my imporession is that idle temps are high.  Are all fans blowing air out of the case? Or into? Or a push and pull?

Comment: I am using the stock Intel heatsink and cooler for the CPU and an additional fan that blows air out of the case. Tj. Max for my CPU as shown by Core Temp is 100 C. Here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/8KQaPEj.png

Comment: My most power hungry CPU with build in GPU is the I5 6600K. I just checked (I am ill and the room hot hot for dutch norms). Room temp is 21C. CPU temp is 27C. That is +6C at idle while driving two screen (2560x1440 and 1920x1200).  A delta of 40C feels **way** off.  Also, we should not keep adding comments, move we can move to chat.

Comment: Sanity checks with several others are now done. Even with ambient 35C then CPU should not be more than +5 to +10 above ambient. Something is really wrong with your setup. Either the airflow though the case, or the cooling is wrong attached, fan not working, or ...

Comment: I put back my 210 today and the CPU temperature didn't go higher than 70 C while playing games so it was the on-die GPU. I should probably re-apply Thermal Paste to see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the downsides of doing so apart from the decreased RAM available to system?

Aside from the RAM as you have already said, there would be no downsides, given the age of the video card you currently have.

> Is there a way to combine the graphics processing power of both the GPUs and output it through the NVIDIA card?

No, there isn't.  The only advantage of using both would be the ability to connect more monitors up to the computer.

> Should I remain on GeForce 210?

That's a decision you would have to make but given that there are no downsides to using the integrated GPU it seems like a pretty good idea to remove the 210.

Comment: did you mean to say "good idea to remove the 210"?

Comment: You're right :-)  I edited my answer to clarify

Comment: What about nVidia Optimus? Would that count as combining the graphics processing power?

Comment: No. Optimus uses either the (relative) low powered Intek GPU or offloads calculation to a semi modern Nvidia GPU and passes the results on to the Intel's output. It does not use both at once for a single application.